# train_and_evaluate tensorflow API not logging all the steps

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, tensorflow-estimator

I have written custom estimator to train and evaluate MNIST Digits . Here I have used the train_and_evaluate API of estimator to train and evaluate .

Here is my training spec snippet 
train_spec = tf.estimator.TrainSpec(input_fn=train_input_fn,hooks=[logging_hook],max_steps=420).

The epoch I have given in train_input_fn is 1 and the batch_size is 100

When i see the console logs I can see logging for steps 1 , 101 , 201 , 295 , 395 .
What I am expecting is 420 steps should get executed and logged  as the batch size is 100 and there are total around 42K samples

As per logging is happening it seems only 4 * 100 images are only processed

Comment: First, please add the definition of `logging_hook`, because that's where your mistake most likely is.
Secondly, the default logging system is configured to log every 100 steps, not every step. This is because logging (aka writing to stdout) takes some time which may end up slowing down your training loop (and normally there is no reason to log after *every* step anyhow, the model needs a few steps to show some meaningful learning).

Comment: ` logging_hook = tf.train.LoggingTensorHook(
        tensors=tensors_to_log, every_n_iter=50)`

Comment: @GPhilo ` logging_hook = tf.train.LoggingTensorHook(
        tensors=tensors_to_log, every_n_iter=50)`     <br/>  I have mentioned the number of steps as 50 and i was expecting the steps to be printed in multiple of 50 .

Comment: Yes, logging_hook does not work.